# Interpreting the objects $\left( \dfrac{\partial x^i}{\partial y^j} \right)_p$

Tags: differential-geometry

> Let $M = (\Bbb R^2, \tau)$, where $\tau$ is the standard topology be a topological manifold with atlas $\mathcal{A} = \{ (\Bbb R^2, x), (\Bbb R^2, y) \}$ where $x(a,b) = (a,b)$ and $y(a,b) = (a, b+a^3)$. Calculate the objects $\left( \dfrac{\partial x^i}{\partial y^j} \right)_p$.

I managed to calculate this by first finding the inverse of $y$ which is $y^{-1}(u,v) = (u, v - u^3)$ and then by definition $$\begin{align*}\left( \dfrac{\partial x^1}{\partial y^1} \right)_p &= \partial_1(x^1 \circ y^{-1})(y(p)) = 1 \\ \left( \dfrac{\partial x^2}{\partial y^1} \right)_p &= \partial_1(x^2 \circ y^{-1})(y(p)) = -2a^2 \\ \left( \dfrac{\partial x^1}{\partial y^2} \right)_p &= \partial_2(x^1 \circ y^{-1})(y(p)) = 0 \\ \left( \dfrac{\partial x^2}{\partial y^2} \right)_p &= \partial_2(x^2 \circ y^{-1})(y(p)) = 1 \end{align*}$$

but I have some trouble understanding what I've calculated. The first point is that it would seem that $\left( \dfrac{\partial x^1}{\partial y^1} \right)_p$ has some abuse of notation as it apparently represents the partial derivatives in coordinates even if $x$ is a map from the manifold.

The second point is that what are the objects $\left( \dfrac{\partial x^i}{\partial y^j} \right)_p$ representing? Am I just calculating the basis vectors for $T_pM$ at $p$ or is there more to it than that?

Comment: that's why we're calculating the actual partials of $x^i\circ y^{-1}$. Composing with $y^{-1}$ now gives you a function defined not on the manifold itself, but on open subset of the vector space $\Bbb{R}^n$ ($n=2$ in your case), thought of in the usual multivariable calculus sense (I know this can be slightly confusing when your manifold itself is $\Bbb{R}^n$, but you have to learn to distinguish the different roles played by $\Bbb{R}^n$; smooth manifold, real vector space etc). So, you're calculating partial derivatives of that new function, as usual.

Comment: @peek-a-boo I see, is it still that the object $\left( \dfrac{\partial x^i}{\partial y^j} \right)_p$ is representing a basis vector for $T_p \Bbb R^n$ or should it be $\left( \dfrac{\partial}{\partial y^j} \right)_p$?

Comment: The first is just a number. The second represents a tangent vector (induced by the coordinate chart $y$).

Comment: more completely, the numbers (or once you arrange them into a matrix) $\frac{\partial x^i}{\partial y^j}(p)$ are the coefficients necessary to change between the two bases $\left\{\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}(p)\right\}_{i=1}^n$ and $\left\{\frac{\partial}{\partial y^j}(p)\right\}_{j=1}^n$ of $T_p\Bbb{R}^n$.